# How to Draw Gantt chart using chart js or other libraries

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, charts, chart.js

I want to draw Gantt chart like below

[image]

There is no option to draw Gantt chart in chart js. is it possible?? if not possible please suggest me some charting libraries to draw graph like this

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I suggest you **Scatter Chart**. In Scatter Charts, you can draw multiple independent lines. As you can see from the below image.
[image]

[**Sample Code**]

```
var scatterChart = new Chart(ctx1, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            datasets: [
            {

                label: 'Scatter Dataset',
                backgroundColor: "rgba(246,156,85,1)",
                borderColor: "rgba(246,156,85,1)",
                fill: false,
                borderWidth : 15,
                pointRadius : 0,
                data: [
                    {
                        x: 0,
                        y: 9
                    }, {
                        x: 3,
                        y: 9
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                backgroundColor: "rgba(208,255,154,1)",
                borderColor: "rgba(208,255,154,1)",
                fill: false,
                borderWidth : 15,
                pointRadius : 0,
                data: [
                    {
                        x: 3,
                        y: 7
                    }, {
                        x: 5,
                        y: 7
                    }
                ]
            },
            {

                label: 'Scatter Dataset',
                backgroundColor: "rgba(246,156,85,1)",
                borderColor: "rgba(246,156,85,1)",
                fill: false,
                borderWidth : 15,
                pointRadius : 0,
                data: [
                    {
                        x: 5,
                        y: 5
                    }, {
                        x: 10,
                        y: 5
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                backgroundColor: "rgba(208,255,154,1)",
                borderColor: "rgba(208,255,154,1)",
                fill: false,
                borderWidth : 15,
                pointRadius : 0,
                data: [
                    {
                        x: 10,
                        y: 3
                    }, {
                        x: 13,
                        y: 3
                    }
                ]
            }
            ]
        },
        options: {
            legend : {
                display : false
            },
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    type: 'linear',
                    position: 'bottom',
                    ticks : {
                        beginAtzero :true,
                        stepSize : 1
                    }
                }],
                yAxes : [{
                    scaleLabel : {
                        display : false
                    },
                    ticks : {
                        beginAtZero :true,
                        max : 10
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    });
```

Rest the configuration like colors or if you want to hide the y axes do it as your project required.

Comment: Could you please provide URL with Chart library?

Comment: @Sanjay Dutt Can we assign date values for the x-axes in the chart

Answer (score 11):

**EDIT** this method would not work efficiently for more complicated cases where multiple bars need to be shown for a single Y value.

I would go with a **stacked horizontalbar** chart of two datasets. The first dataset would be transparent and used to offset the second dataset which is your actual data. The code below prevents tooltip from appearing for the first dataset as well.

[image]

http://codepen.io/pursianKatze/pen/OmbWvZ?editors=1111

**[SAMPLE CODE]**

```js
var barOptions_stacked = {
    hover :{
        animationDuration:10
    },
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            label:"Duration",
            ticks: {
                beginAtZero:true,
                fontFamily: "'Open Sans Bold', sans-serif",
                fontSize:11
            },
            scaleLabel:{
                display:false
            },
            gridLines: {
            }, 
            stacked: true
        }],
        yAxes: [{
            gridLines: {
                display:false,
                color: "#fff",
                zeroLineColor: "#fff",
                zeroLineWidth: 0
            },
            ticks: {
                fontFamily: "'Open Sans Bold', sans-serif",
                fontSize:11
            },
            stacked: true
        }]
    },
    legend:{
        display:false
    },
};

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {    
    type: 'horizontalBar',
    data: {
        labels: ["1", "2", "3", "4"],
        
        datasets: [{
            data: [50,150, 300, 400, 500],
            backgroundColor: "rgba(63,103,126,0)",
            hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(50,90,100,0)"
            
        },{
            data: [100, 100, 200, 200, 100],
            backgroundColor: ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow'],
        }]
    },
    options: barOptions_stacked,
});

// this part to make the tooltip only active on your real dataset
var originalGetElementAtEvent = myChart.getElementAtEvent;
myChart.getElementAtEvent = function (e) {
    return originalGetElementAtEvent.apply(this, arguments).filter(function (e) {
        return e._datasetIndex === 1;
    });
}
```

```css
.graph_container{
  display:block;
  width:600px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.1.3/Chart.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
<div class="graph_container">
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Another open source option is [Frappé Gantt](https://frappe.github.io/gantt/)

Comment: HI! could you please hlp me with using Frappe gantt with Angular? i'm stuck at the import of the frappe.min.js.Angular doesn't let me define gant = new Gantt().

Answer (score 2):

You can try this library [jQuery.Gantt](http://taitems.github.io/jQuery.Gantt/). It is very useful and provide lots of options to draw Gantt Chart

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution to this is to use quickchart.io

The good support people at quickchart.io were kind enough to send me an example that includes dates on the x-axis unlike some of the answers above. You can access the example [here](https://quickchart.io/sandbox#%7B%0A%20%20%20%20type%3A%20%27horizontalBar%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20data%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20labels%3A%20%5B%27Part%201%27%2C%20%27Part%202%27%2C%20%27Part%203%27%2C%20%27Part%204%27%2C%20%27Part%205%27%2C%20%27Part%206%27%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20datasets%3A%20%5B%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20data%3A%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5Bnew%20Date(%272021-02-01%27)%2C%20new%20Date(%272021-05-01%27)%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5Bnew%20Date(%272021-05-10%27)%2C%20new%20Date(%272021-07-01%27)%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5Bnew%20Date(%272021-04-20%27)%2C%20new%20Date(%272021-11-31%27)%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5Bnew%20Date(%272021-08-01%27)%2C%20new%20Date(%272021-09-01%27)%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5Bnew%20Date(%272021-02-10%27)%2C%20new%20Date(%272021-07-01%27)%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5Bnew%20Date(%272021-07-20%27)%2C%20new%20Date(%272021-11-31%27)%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20backgroundColor%3A%20%5B%27rgb(255%2C%2099%2C%20132%2C%201.0)%27%2C%20%27rgba(255%2C%2099%2C%20132%2C%201.0)%27%2C%20%27rgba(255%2C%20206%2C%2086%2C%201.0)%27%2C%20%27rgba(255%2C%20206%2C%2086%2C%201.0)%27%2C%20%27rgba(255%2C%20206%2C%2086%2C%200.2)%27%2C%20undefined%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%20%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20options%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20legend%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20display%3A%20false%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20annotation%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20annotations%3A%20%5B%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20type%3A%20%27line%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20mode%3A%20%27vertical%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20scaleID%3A%20%27x-axis-0%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20value%3A%20new%20Date(%272021-10-30%27)%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20borderColor%3A%20%27red%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20borderWidth%3A%201%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20label%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20enabled%3A%20true%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20content%3A%20%27Deadline%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20position%3A%20%27top%27%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20scales%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20xAxes%3A%20%5B%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20position%3A%20%27top%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20type%3A%20%27time%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20time%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20unit%3A%20%27month%27%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20ticks%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20min%3A%20new%20Date(%272021-01-01%27)%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20max%3A%20new%20Date(%272022-01-01%27)%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%7D).

If you would then like to embed a Gantt chart into Gmail email you would first need to send the HTML to a service such as htmlcsstoimage.com

[image: Example output]

Answer (score 0):

I think it's easier with Highcharts.
Check out [their documentation](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/gantt/project-management/grid-light).

It's really easy to use when it comes to project management charts.

Here is [a JSFiddle link to example usage](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/gantt/demo/project-management).

```js
   

 var today = new Date(),
    day = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
    // Utility functions
    dateFormat = Highcharts.dateFormat,
    defined = Highcharts.defined,
    isObject = Highcharts.isObject;

// Set to 00:00:00:000 today
today.setUTCHours(0);
today.setUTCMinutes(0);
today.setUTCSeconds(0);
today.setUTCMilliseconds(0);
today = today.getTime();

Highcharts.ganttChart('container', {
    series: [{
        name: 'Offices',
        data: [{
            name: 'New offices',
            id: 'new_offices',
            owner: 'Peter'
        }, {
            name: 'Prepare office building',
            id: 'prepare_building',
            parent: 'new_offices',
            start: today - (2 * day),
            end: today + (6 * day),
            completed: {
                amount: 0.2
            },
            owner: 'Linda'
        }, {
            name: 'Inspect building',
            id: 'inspect_building',
            dependency: 'prepare_building',
            parent: 'new_offices',
            start: today + 6 * day,
            end: today + 8 * day,
            owner: 'Ivy'
        }, {
            name: 'Passed inspection',
            id: 'passed_inspection',
            dependency: 'inspect_building',
            parent: 'new_offices',
            start: today + 9.5 * day,
            milestone: true,
            owner: 'Peter'
        }, {
            name: 'Relocate',
            id: 'relocate',
            dependency: 'passed_inspection',
            parent: 'new_offices',
            owner: 'Josh'
        }, {
            name: 'Relocate staff',
            id: 'relocate_staff',
            parent: 'relocate',
            start: today + 10 * day,
            end: today + 11 * day,
            owner: 'Mark'
        }, {
            name: 'Relocate test facility',
            dependency: 'relocate_staff',
            parent: 'relocate',
            start: today + 11 * day,
            end: today + 13 * day,
            owner: 'Anne'
        }, {
            name: 'Relocate cantina',
            dependency: 'relocate_staff',
            parent: 'relocate',
            start: today + 11 * day,
            end: today + 14 * day
        }]
    }, {
        name: 'Product',
        data: [{
            name: 'New product launch',
            id: 'new_product',
            owner: 'Peter'
        }, {
            name: 'Development',
            id: 'development',
            parent: 'new_product',
            start: today - day,
            end: today + (11 * day),
            completed: {
                amount: 0.6,
                fill: '#e80'
            },
            owner: 'Susan'
        }, {
            name: 'Beta',
            id: 'beta',
            dependency: 'development',
            parent: 'new_product',
            start: today + 12.5 * day,
            milestone: true,
            owner: 'Peter'
        }, {
            name: 'Final development',
            id: 'finalize',
            dependency: 'beta',
            parent: 'new_product',
            start: today + 13 * day,
            end: today + 17 * day
        }, {
            name: 'Launch',
            dependency: 'finalize',
            parent: 'new_product',
            start: today + 17.5 * day,
            milestone: true,
            owner: 'Peter'
        }]
    }],
    tooltip: {
        pointFormatter: function () {
            var point = this,
                format = '%e. %b',
                options = point.options,
                completed = options.completed,
                amount = isObject(completed) ? completed.amount : completed,
                status = ((amount || 0) * 100) + '%',
                lines;

            lines = [{
                value: point.name,
                style: 'font-weight: bold;'
            }, {
                title: 'Start',
                value: dateFormat(format, point.start)
            }, {
                visible: !options.milestone,
                title: 'End',
                value: dateFormat(format, point.end)
            }, {
                title: 'Completed',
                value: status
            }, {
                title: 'Owner',
                value: options.owner || 'unassigned'
            }];

            return lines.reduce(function (str, line) {
                var s = '',
                    style = (
                        defined(line.style) ? line.style : 'font-size: 0.8em;'
                    );
                if (line.visible !== false) {
                    s = (
                        '<span style="' + style + '">' +
                        (defined(line.title) ? line.title + ': ' : '') +
                        (defined(line.value) ? line.value : '') +
                        '</span><br/>'
                    );
                }
                return str + s;
            }, '');
        }
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Gantt Project Management'
    },
    xAxis: {
        currentDateIndicator: true,
        min: today - 3 * day,
        max: today + 18 * day
    }
});
```

```css
#container {
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: 1em auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/gantt/highcharts-gantt.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/gantt/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: run the code to see how it works . the code is self explanatary. you just need to define your data set and the time period of the gant chart