# How to change color and width of bars in chart.js in angular

Tags: angular, chart.js

I'm working on creating a Gantt chart. To make it appealing and follow with my business requirement I need to change color and width of said bars. I'm using chart.js in angular for this. And following this working [**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gantt-chart-wmbuel?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) example.

I tried adding `[colors]` in html and defining values in TS, but was't able to resolve the issue.

Also if there is any other package available that I can use to create gantt will also help, I want to show with tasks start-date, end-date and a horizontal line showing progress or time booked for each task

**TS & HTML**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import "chartjs-plugin-datalabels";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  MS_PER_DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;

  data = [
    {
      task: "Task 1",
      startDate: "2018-04-08 00:00:00.000",
      endDate: "2018-06-08 00:00:00.000"
    },
    {
      task: "Task 2",
      startDate: "2018-05-08 00:00:00.000",
      endDate: "2018-07-19 00:00:00.000"
    },
    {
      task: "Task 3",
      startDate: "2018-07-08 00:00:00.000",
      endDate: "2018-09-08 00:00:00.000"
    },
    { task: "Growth Stages" }
  ];

  data1 = [
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {
      task: "VP",
      startDate: "2018-04-21 00:00:00.000",
      endDate: "2018-05-08 00:00:00.000"
    }
  ];

  data2 = [
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {
      task: "VE",
      startDate: "2018-05-09 00:00:00.000",
      endDate: "2018-06-08 00:00:00.000"
    }
  ];

  chartData;
  options;
  plantingDays = "2018-04-01 00:00:00.000";

  constructor() {}

  lables = ["Task 1", "Task 2", "Task 3", "Growth Stages"];
  stages = ["VP", "VE", "V6", "VTR1"];

  createChart() {
    const that = this;
    this.chartData = {
      // labels: this.data.map(t => t.task),
      labels: this.lables,
      datasets: [
        {
          data: this.data.map(t => {
            return this.dateDiffInDays(
              new Date(this.plantingDays),
              new Date(t.startDate)
            );
          }),
          datalabels: {
            color: "#025ced",
            formatter: function(value, context) {
              return "";
            }
          },
          backgroundColor: "rgba(63,103,126,0)",
          hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(50,90,100,0)"
        },
        {
          data: this.data.map(t => {
            return this.dateDiffInDays(
              new Date(t.startDate),
              new Date(t.endDate)
            );
          }),
          datalabels: {
            color: "#025ced",
            formatter: function(value, context) {
              return "";
            }
          }
        },
        {
          data: this.data1.map(t => {
            return this.dateDiffInDays(
              new Date(t.startDate),
              new Date(t.endDate)
            );
          }),
          datalabels: {
            color: "#025ced",
            formatter: function(value, context) {
              return that.stages[0];
            }
          }
        },
        {
          data: this.data2.map(t => {
            return this.dateDiffInDays(
              new Date(t.startDate),
              new Date(t.endDate)
            );
          }),
          datalabels: {
            color: "#025ced",
            formatter: function(value, context) {
              return that.stages[1];
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    };

    this.options = {
      maintainAspectRatio: false,
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: "Title of Chart"
      },
      legend: { display: false },
      tooltips: {
        mode: "index",
        callbacks: {
          label: function(tooltipItem, d) {
            let label = d.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label || "";
            const date = new Date(that.plantingDays);
            if (tooltipItem.datasetIndex === 0) {
              const diff = that.dateDiffInDays(
                date,
                new Date(that.data[tooltipItem.index].startDate)
              );
              date.setDate(diff + 1);
              label += "Start Date: " + that.getDate(date);
            } else if (tooltipItem.datasetIndex === 1) {
              const diff = that.dateDiffInDays(
                date,
                new Date(that.data[tooltipItem.index].endDate)
              );
              date.setDate(diff + 1);
              label += "End Date: " + that.getDate(date);
            }
            return label;
          }
        }
      },
      scales: {
        xAxes: [
          {
            stacked: true,
            ticks: {
              callback: function(value, index, values) {
                const date = new Date(that.plantingDays);
                date.setDate(value);
                return that.getDate(date);
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        yAxes: [
          {
            stacked: true
          }
        ]
      }
    };
  }

  getDate(date) {
    return (
      date.getFullYear() +
      "-" +
      ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).substr(-2) +
      "-" +
      ("0" + date.getDate()).substr(-2)
    );
  }

  dateDiffInDays(a, b) {
    // Discard the time and time-zone information.
    const utc1 = Date.UTC(a.getFullYear(), a.getMonth(), a.getDate());
    const utc2 = Date.UTC(b.getFullYear(), b.getMonth(), b.getDate());

    return Math.floor((utc2 - utc1) / this.MS_PER_DAY);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.createChart();
  }
}
```

```html
<chart class="chart" type="horizontalBar" [data]="chartData" [options]="options"></chart>
```

Comment: have u try this one => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41259441/how-to-draw-gantt-chart-using-chart-js-or-other-libraries

Comment: tried https://frappe.io/gantt, not able to render in angular. Shows blank.